# How to set he height of the container of my pieChart in amcharts?

Tags: javascript, laravel, amcharts

I have a pie chart and my problem is that my display labels exceed my container. I wanted to adjust the height of my container but it's not working. I am using a pie chart of amcharts. I hope someone could help me. Here are my codes.

Here is my javascript

```
function regionPie(trigger){
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    var chart = am4core.create("m_chart_industry_composition", am4charts.PieChart);
    chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);}}
```

Here is my blade

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-8">
      <div id="m_chart_industry_composition">
       </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion will be a good help.

Comment: You want your container <div> to automatically grow to contain all the labels?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### you should use [Responsive feature for amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/making-charts-responsive/#Enabling_responsive_features)

There are some custom rules to make charts more reliable for all type of screens and setups.

**Hope this might be helpful to you**

Comment: Your comment provides information about wrong version (amCharts 4). Question was related to amCharts 4. I suggest you remove your answer.